# STA thread required for AutoCompleteMode set to SuggestAppend on ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

When using a ComboBox set the AutoCompleteMode to SuggestAppend in the designer, when accessing the init of that form through a background worker, the following exception is thrown:

"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made"

I know how to fix the problem, but what I am asking is **why** an STA thread is required to set this property?

Note: This is using WinForms, .NET 3.5, C#